# php 5 variable from javascript not unset

Tags: php, unset

Note: clicking on the left chess piece at http://communitychessclub.com/rabren/index.php?clear=1 is supposed to unset $choice and reload the page. But it just reloads the page.

I want to check for a variable state set in javascript.

```
 onclick="window.location='index.php?clear=1'
```

and `if clear == "1"` I want to reset `$choice_1` with:

```
if ($_GET['clear']=="1") {empty($_SESSION['choice_1']);}
```

and rebuild the array and generate new image references.

But what I have doesn't work; it never resets or empties `$choice_1`

I have an image with a link to the home page:

```
<img onclick="window.location='index.php?clear=1'; return false;" 
src="images/WL<?php echo $_SESSION['choice_1'];?>.png" alt="pieces" width=128 height=128>
```

and I have at the top of index.php:

image set:

```
<?php 

if ($_GET['clear']=="1") {empty($_SESSION['choice_1']);}

if(!isset($_SESSION['choice_1'])) {
$chessmen = array("N","Q","R","B","K","P"); 

$random_piece = array_rand($chessmen); 
$_SESSION['choice_1'] = $chessmen[$random_piece];

unset($chessmen[$random_piece]);

$random_piece = array_rand($chessmen); 
$_SESSION['choice_2'] = $chessmen[$random_piece];
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty only determines whether a variable is empty, use unset.

```
if ($_GET['clear']=="1") {unset($_SESSION['choice_1']);}
```